# Importing package from a virtual environment in Python 3.6

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm trying to run TensorFlow on a virtual environment that I've created and which runs Python 3.6.8 using VS Code (I know anaconda is the preferred way to go but I have to use VS Code). However, when I try to import the package into my .py file, it says that the TensorFlow module cannot be found.

My settings.json file has the following data:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\AI\\venv36\\Scripts\\python"
}
```

The above was implemented in accordance with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wuuiga0wKdQ. I know that TensorFlow has been installed since when I go to the virtual environment directory and try to import it within the CLI, it imports the module without any issues.

The TensorFlow module is located in the path:  C:\Users\user\Desktop\AI\venv36\Lib\site-packages

But when I put the above path in the settings.json file, it still didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provide, please refer to the following:

1. To use python in VS Code, please make sure that the 'python' extension has been installed.

   [image]
2. If you are using a 'Windows' system, you need to use "python.exe" when setting ["python.pythonPath](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter)".
3. Please check whether the python environment displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code is consistent with the python environment used by the VS Code terminal.

   ( If they use different pythons, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the python environment selected in the lower left corner of VS Code. )

   [image]

More reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: So I had gotten Python to run on VS Code. That part was okay. It's just that the package installed in the virtual environment isn't being read. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @Spartacus98 -Why do you say "_package installed in the virtual environment isn't being read_"? Does it show any "module not found" information? If the code can run, please try reloading VS Code to make it recognized.

Comment: Yep, it shows a "module not found" error. I did try reloading VS Code but that didn't help. I've confirmed that the module has been installed since when I open up cmd and try importing the module, it works beautifully.

Comment: @Spartacus98 -Please use the command "python --version" in "cmd" to check the currently used python, and check whether it is the same as the python in "cmd" in the VS Code terminal.

Comment: @Spartacus98 -If they use the same python and it still doesn't work, please try to reinstall the required modules in the VS Code terminal. (_pip install module_name_)

Comment: My default is Python3.9. However, since I want to install Tensorflow, I had to run a virtual environment with Python3.6 (theres no tensorflow support for Python3.8+). So, my Python version is different but how would that come into play?

Comment: @Spartacus98 -Why do you say "there no tensorflow support for Python3.8+"? I am using the [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) of python 3.8.3, which successfully installed the module "tensorflow".
In addition, if you want to use python3.6, please select this environment in the lower left corner of VS Code, and then use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter this environment.

Comment: I thought there wasn't support for Python 3.8+ since I couldn't pip install tensorflow and I'm using Python3.9 and when I checked on the net, I found a Github link with the same issue and it was mentioned there that there was no support https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39130. Could you tell me how you installed tensorflow on your system?

Comment: @Spartacus98 -I installed the module "tensorflow" using the command "[pip install tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/)". Have you tried this command? What does the terminal display when this command is used?

Comment: When I try it out, I get this error: pip Install Error: don't could find version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Comment: @Spartacus98 -If your python3.9 environment cannot install this module, please try to install this module in the python3.6 virtual environment you created. For the python environment in VS Code, you could refer to: [Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: I tried that and that's what brought me to the question I posted in the first place. :(

Comment: @Spartacus98 -If this is possible, please try to reinstall [python](https://www.python.org/), I can install this module using python3.8 in VS Code.

Comment: I guess that's the only thing left to do then. I'll try that. Thanks so much for your help!